# Getting a fatal error on $query-execute();

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

Hi im new to coding and im following a tutorial on building a blog with php and mysql.

This is my error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   boolean in /homepages/46/d669275675/htdocs/blog/blog.php:5 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /homepages/46/d669275675/htdocs/blog/blog.php on line 5

my code looks like this

```
<?php
// connect to database
include('includes/db_connect.php');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 100) AS body, category 
                       FROM posts 
                       INNER JOIN categories 
                       ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id 
                       order by post_id desc");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);
?>
```

Comment: Your prepare statement failed. Check for errors.

Comment: thanks for your reply, how would I check for errors? I'm really new to this ad been going round in circles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: cheers guys I've fixed it, it was the prepare statement. Thanks for your help